# Error generating google cloud endpoint client libraries

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-eclipse-plugin

During last weeks I've been developing an app using **GAE/J** and **Google Cloud Endpoints**. I created my custom endpoints (using annotations) and although I had quite a lot of problems, I could solve them and everything was working rather fine.

But now (22/04/2013) I tried to make changes in an endpoint method, and suddenly the **Google Eclipse Plugin** is not generating the client libraries anymore!

I tried to delete all the generated api files from my project, but nothing worked. I've even downloaded Eclipse again, installed all the last versions of GPE and GAE SDK and started a new project from scratch, but I'm getting the same error...

---

*EDIT*: After trying absolutely **EVERYTHING**, it seems that there must be a problem with *Google's end*. It seems that GPE uses a `CloudClientLibGenerator`, which hasn't been working at least for the last...

### [ 75 hours ... ]

And now I'm wondering:

1. Why the hell they need a cloud generator to generate the code of the endpoints, if they have all the necessary info locally (code, libraries, etc...)? or they haven't?
2. I'm using the *free version* of GAE, developing an app for the university (my MSc final project), but what if I was developing a real app paying for GAE? Isn't this a bit too *shoddy*?

Anyway, I think the word is *dis-end-ppointment* with Endpoints...

---

Note: I've opened [**this issue**](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9214) in Google Code.

*EDIT*: **Responses from Google Project Member**: "*There's currently an issue with Endpoints in general, which is obfuscating any current or prior issues with library generation. I'll update when the current issue is resolved.*"

"*We're working to get the problem fixed ASAP. We will post an update once the problem is resolved.*"

### UPDATE: Some users are now posting comments in the issue above pointing out that the problem is solved! There's no official comment from Google though. Unfortunately I can't check it for the moment...

---

### POSSIBLE WORKAROUND:

You have to change to a **previous GAE SDK version**. Both **1.7.5** and **1.7.6** are working. You can download Java version from [**here**](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/downloads/detail?name=appengine-java-sdk-1.7.5.zip&can=2&q=label:OpSys-All).

I've tried and the endpoint library generation is working!!! And also the APIs Explorer in the development server, so we can keep developing while waiting for the bug to be fixed, what will happen **tomorrow** according to Google team...

And suddenly my already deployed endpoints, which were not working, are working again! (although the client generation is still not working with SDK 1.7.7)

*EDIT*: From Google they're saying that the generation from command line is working as well.

---

Stacktrace of the exception thrown while trying to generate client libraries (in GPE Error Log):

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createClientLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:121)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:242)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:364)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:507)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{"error": {"message": "Bad Request", "code": 400, "errors": [{"message": "api error", "debug_info": "Could not parse api"}]}}
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1155)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.postRequest(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:52)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.generateClientLib(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:43)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: Same problem with me too. The thing with Google is that you can never be too careful/trustful when using any of their "experimental apis". They change and break without any notice or clue. Happens with me time after time. :-(

Comment: Did anyone try the Command Line method of generating the Cloud Endpoint Library? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/gen_clients

Comment: In fact I didn't, but I don't think it'd make any changes, because after all the generation process should be the same, regardless of if it's being called from command line or from GPE, right? Moreover, the comment of the Google project member doesn't make me think that there's any solution for the moment, but waiting...

Comment: Yup, you are right. Even my apps api explorer does not respond. https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://<yourapp>.appspot.com/_ah/api#p/

Comment: that's true, I've edited. Until now at least I could access my edpoints... this is just amazing! I need it to be fixed soon... for the moment I want to forget about this situation so I'm going to watch Champions League match ;)

Comment: @HariKrishnaGanji my already deployed endpoints are working again in the APIs Explorer.

Comment: Great. I have managed to make my app back & running too. I am lucky that I had to wait only for a few hours unlike you. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now fixed in GPE 3.2.3, and on the service side. You can now use App Engine 1.7.7.

There is still one issue remaining:

https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=191

and it will be fixed on Monday.

Comment: The status of this bug is also 'fixed' now.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. No fix yet it seems.  It started happening all of a sudden.  I was able to generate cloud endpoint client libraries fine yesterday. But now, no.  And even creating a new template project gives the error.  So guessing from the error, it looks to be a problem at Google's end.

An open issue has been logged:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9180

Comment: Thanks for the info @Phil. Yes, it's what I'm guessing too... it's been already 12h at least, I need it to be fixed! I'll be checking the issue in google code...

Comment: I hate to be pedantic, but I think this could be a comment on the question, not an answer.