# Issues with Appengine Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

During the last 2 days I have been unable to update my endpoints.  My logs state successful deployment and update, but the discovery document returns a 502.  Anyone else having issues??

Java runtime.

Update:  I've tried changing to an older version of that is know to work and that is not working either.  My all endpoints are down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm that Endpoints is down at the moment, we're working on it.

Edit: the service should be back now.

Comment: up and running now.  Thank!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem at the Moment with Google Cloud Endpoints in general.

Follow this StackOverflow Question : [Error generating google cloud endpoint client libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158013/error-generating-google-cloud-endpoint-client-libraries)

and it associated Issue on Google Code : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9214

Comment: I have actually successfully generated the client libs.

Comment: I am guessing this related fix must have solved it! : https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=117. But can you please confirm if your deployed endpoint server changes are begin reflected on Google App Engine.