# Google app engine: 502 bad gateway

Tags: google-app-engine

all my projects on Google app engine cannot access the cloud endpoints now. Just want to know if it's my own problem or google app engine is down now? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there was an outage on the Google Side. : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16199616/1300982

I guess the service must be up and running now. Please check!