# Generating Cloud Endpoint has encountered errors and is not complete

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, gae-eclipse-plugin

The title line is the error I get from eclipse when I right click my project to `Google > Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Library`. I can run the endpoint fine as a `Web Application` so  there is no error in the code that I or the compiler can detect. Does anyone know why the error is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a problem at the Moment with Google Clound Endpoints in general.

Follow this Stackoverflow Question : [Error generating google cloud endpoint client libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158013/error-generating-google-cloud-endpoint-client-libraries)

and it associated Issue on Google Code : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9214

Comment: Thanks, I guess. I see the slew of posts and up-votes. Google must be pissing off a lot of customers right now. I know I haven't had sleep in the past two days wondering what the hell I am doing wrong.

Comment: Well, that's what happens to me time after time for using Google's so called "Experimental APIs". Happened with Cloud Storage API, Merchant API, and now this. The bad part is that you don't get to know it so easily. :-)