# How to change from google eclipse plugin 1.7.7 to 1.7.5

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-eclipse-plugin, gae-eclipse-plugin

Due to [a bug in the google sphere](https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=117) I need to change from GEP 1.7.7 to version 1.7.5 or 1.7.6. How would I effect that change? I look in the eclipse marketplace, from within eclipse, but the plugins are arranged by eclipse versions such as 3.6, 3.7, 3.8/4.2. Which one would be 1.7.5 or 1.7.6? I am using eclipse Juno Service Release 2 on mac osx.

Also, would that be the same as `SDK(App-engine 1.7.6)` or `SDK(App-engine 1.7.5)`

Comment: This has been fixed in GPE 3.2.3. You can now use App Engine 1.7.7. See details here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16245896/1769350

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the downgrade manually by download do it by downloading the SDK.

Try this link https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/downloads/detail?name=appengine-java-sdk-1.7.5.zip&can=2&q=label%3AOpSys-All

Then you have to add it to Eclipse by going into:

> Window > Preferences > Google > App Engine.

Then you click on the "Add" button, and you add the folder where you downloaded the old SDK

Once added you have to configure the project by going into:

> Properties > Google > App Engine, and there you select the 1-7-5 SDK

And you should be all set